# Braintree 3D Secure 2 implementation on magento 2.2 Error Class League\ISO3166\ISO3166 does not exist

Tags: magento2.2

Has anyone from magento community upgraded the Braintree module to version 3.4.1 . i tried to install it through composer via the following command ,

```
composer require paypal/module-braintree:3.4.1 --no-update
```

but got the following error

`[InvalidArgumentException]

  Could not find a matching version of package paypal/module-braintree. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and

   that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).`

so i downloaded the module from the magento marketplace instead 
https://marketplace.magento.com/paypal-module-braintree.html

and placed the module to vendor/magento/module-braintree
The module has been installed alright but when payment is made on frontend , it throws error `Class League\ISO3166\ISO3166 does not exist`

can anyone suggest how to proceed further ?

Comment: Any update on this? Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: no , our magento version was 2.2  so  it was  not possible for  us to  even update the braintree module to the latest version as it was not compatible with 2.2 , this  is  what i  believe . So i downgraded  the module to a lower version .